# Move points along line

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to move a group of points along a line when dragging one point by hand? Context: I use qgis to draw in kilometrage for rivers. Using toolbox - points along geometry. Sometimes, the official kilometrage is not really exact 1km. So i have to fit my kilometer points to the official kilometrage. I want to drag one point by hand along the river line, and all points after this point should move this for distance, following the river line.